# Dynamic favicon that persists after refreshing the browser

Tags: angular, typescript, favicon

We have a web application written in Angular (4.3.4 to be exact) that changes settings based on the user account that logs in at the start (each user belongs to a company, which has it's own logo/favicon etc.)

On login, we retrieve the settings from the users database and set them inside the local cache. One of these settings is a URL to a favicon that they have set themselves.

Currently, I execute some jQuery that locates the favicon element inside the `<head>` tags that changes the `href` attribute:

```
private changeFavicon(value: string): void {
    $('#favicon').attr('href', value);
}
```

But, upon a page refresh, this data is gone and it reverts back to the original favicon (a backup we have stored as an image in /resources/)

The only way I can see solving this problem is adding a 'CanLoad' service that set it every time a route is initialised, but this will have to be added to every route (as a user can obviously refresh on every page) which does not seem the best route to take.

Is there a way I can persist these changes across refreshes?

Comment: can you set a cookie and serve favicon.ico dynamically?

Comment: @GradyPlayer I don't see why not - would you be able to provide an example?

Comment: sorry, I dont front end :)